Why doesn't the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+ : xy\geq1\}$ have any extreme points?
On a lecture note, there is a theorem stating that if C is convex and compact then there exits an extreme point of C. Then, there is a remark stating that the hypothesis of compactness is crucial and the set of the question is said to be a counter example. I'm failing to see why. For example, why isn't $(1,1)$ an extreme point ? How can one write $(1,1)$ as the middle of two other points in the set ?

Your set doesn’t seem to be connected, so I fail to see how it is convex.

In $\mathbb R^n$, closed convext set has no extreme points iff it contains a line. So I don't think this example can be saved.

The statement is false in all generality, see

Roberts, James W. "A compact convex set with no extreme points."
Studia Mathematica 60.3 (1977): 255-266.

It is true when you have a compact and convex subset of a Haussdorff locally convex topological space. However, just because we take an unbounded convex set doesn't mean it doesn't have extreme points. In your example, taking the connected component with $x > 0$, we have an infinite number of extreme points, precisely those verifying the equations $x > 0$ and $xy=1$.

How can one prove your last point ? Using the strict convexity of the function $x\in\mathbb{R}_+^*\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ ?

Yes, for example, or writing things down by hand.

This set is not convex: e.g. it contains $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ but not $(0,0)$.
Perhaps there's a typo and it should have been $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x + y \ge 1\}$.

Sorry, there is indeed a typo and we actually have $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+$. I just edited the question.
